# Dynamics 365: How do i concatenate/combine strings in a Action/Work flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

How do i concatenate/combine strings in a Action/Work flow?

I am trying to create a action/workflow that auto populates a disabled text box base on two other text box with a space in between (i.e., Textbox1 & " " & Textbox2).

At the last step of the workflow process, "update", i dont see a way to do it.

[image]

Comment: Your question title says Dynamics 365, but your tags say CRM 2011... I'm assuming your title is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is supported.

1. Add `{Detail ID(Detail)}`
2. Click on the textbox, move the mouse
   cursor to the end (<kbd>end</kbd>) and press
   <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>
3. Add `{Drop Off(Detail)}`

Here's an example of the end result:

[image: Example]